# Java DateTime viewing

Tags: java, date, datetime

Hello i'm defining a variable in which i want to stock date-time input.
I gave this variable a format which is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM`.
But in the database it keeps showing me only this format  `yyyy-mm-dd` without `hh:MM`
The code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM");
                  java.util.Date date = sdf1.parse(rs.getString("dateMaint"));
                  java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new Date(date.getTime()); 
                  mc.setDateMaint(sqlStartDate );
```

Comment: Little `m` stands for minutes while `M` stands for months... You'll have to switch them in your code

Comment: Also, a java.sql.Date doesn't have a time portion. So that's not really surprising. Use a Timestamp. And choose the appropriate type for the database column, of course.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. Do you suggest anything using Timestamp ?

Comment: @user3816341  Please search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been covered *many* times already.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static java.sql.Timestamp convertToSqlDateTime(Date utilDate){
        return new java.sql.Timestamp(utilDate.getTime());
}
```

Normally, [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) only returns a date-only value and time will be discarded. So, in order to get time also, `java.sql.TimeStamp` must be used.

**TimeStamp** constructs a `Timestamp` object using a milliseconds time value. The integral seconds are stored in the underlying date value; the fractional seconds are stored in the nanos field of the Timestamp object.

For this purpose, `utilDate.getTime()` is used to return the **number of milliseconds** since `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` represented by this Date Object.

For more information link: [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

Comment: java.sql.date does handle up to milliseconds of precision, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html However you are right that the implementation of date, time, datetime differs accross database vendors.

Comment: @GeeBee Read the javadoc: *To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated*.

Comment: Javadoc also says: *public void setTime(long date)
Sets an existing Date object using the given milliseconds **time** value. If the given milliseconds value contains **time information**, the driver will set the time components to the time in the default time zone (the time zone of the Java virtual machine running the application) that corresponds to zero GMT.*

Answer (score 0):

Also check if the database data type for your data is correct. This is dabase vendor dependant, for example an Oracle *date* type contains both time and date, but MS SQL server *date* means only date part: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx